# Using Group By and Max function together DAX

Tags: group-by, max, dax

I have a table like below:

[image]

and I want to group by the date and name and then order by the MAX of rate. I use such an Expression:

```
NewTable =
CALCULATETABLE (
    Table1,
    GROUPBY ( Table1, Table1[Day], Table1[Name], "maxrate", MAX ( Table1[Rate] ) ))
```

But I receive an error. Can anyone explain how max and group by can be used together in DAX?

Answer (score 3):

Just use SUMMARIZE function instead of GROUPBY:

```
New Table  = SUMMARIZE (Table1, Table1[Day], Table1[Name], "maxrate', MAX(Table1[Rate]))
```

GROUPBY requires an iterator (such as MAXX). For example, let's say your table has rate and quantity, and your want to calculate max amount (rate * quantity). Then you should use GROUPBY:

```
New Table =
GROUPBY (
    Table1,
    Table1[Day],
    Table1[Name],
    "Max Amount", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), Table1[Rate] * Table1[Quantity] )
)
```

Here, you first group table1 by day and name, and then iterate current group, to find max amount.

GROUPBY is very handy in some complicated cases,  but your situation seems straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this to have a dynamic y axis to find the max of different groups.

```
Y axis max bing form fills =
MAXX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        BingConversion,
        'Calendar'[Month Year],
        BingConversion[Creative],--legend field
        "Max Form Fills", SUM ( BingConversion[Formfills] )
    ),
    [Max Form Fills]
) * 1.25
--this measure gives us a dynamic axis with a cusion (*1.25) so that when we have groups in the measure, our axis doesn't go too big
```